# How to fix Tomcat HTTP Status 403: Access to the requested resource has been denied?

Tags: tomcat, http-status-code-403

I am trying to setup Tomcat with my current source code.
I downloaded the zip from tomcat site (6.0.32).

I then put in the config file for my project in `tomcatDir\conf\Catalina\localhost`

I then added the users to `tomcat-users.xml`

When I hit my application using `localhost:8080/<context root>`, I get the login prompt as I am supposed to. After providing the right credentials, the tomcat throws 403 error.
I am able to access the manager with `localhost:8080/manager/`

`tomcat-users.xml`:

```
<role rolename="manager"/>
<role rolename="admin"/>
<user username="admin" password="5c50nD" roles="admin,manager"/>
<user username="nih\kishorev" password="altum" roles="admin,manager"/>
```

Comment: I am having the same problem...did you manage to solve it? I can access the status page but the manager app gives this error..

Answer (score 3):

You should choose manager roles which are defined by tomcat instead of admin or manager.

```
manager-gui - Allows access to the html interface
manager-script - Allows access to the plain text interface
manager-jmx - Allows access to the JMX proxy interface
manager-status - Allows access to the read-only status pages
```

link to [Configuring Manager Application access in tomcat](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/manager-howto.html#Configuring%20Manager%20Application%20Access)

Answer (score 2):

You need to change the form actions to Post, apparently there is a problem with the GET method on the 6.0.32 version of tomcat, it should be fixed in 6.0.33 version of tomcat.

[link to tomcat bugzilla](https://issues.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=51147)

Answer (score 2):

This one works for me

```
<role rolename="manager"/>
<user username="admin" password="admin" roles="manager"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. I needed to do two things. In the
web.xml you have to define BASIC or an other method leading to a form based login prompt and a role-name for example Admin:

```
    <security-constraint>   
    <web-resource-collection>   
        <web-resource-name>Protected Admin Area</web-resource-name>   
        <url-pattern>/Admin</url-pattern>   
    </web-resource-collection>
    <auth-constraint>
        <role-name>Admin</role-name>
    </auth-constraint>   
  </security-constraint>  
  <login-config>   
        <auth-method>BASIC</auth-method>
  </login-config>
```

In the tomcat-users.xml add a user with the role Admin, or if you use a graphic interface like eclipse do the following:[image]

Answer (score 0):

Please check you web.xml In that put

`admin` instead of `AllAuthenticatedUsers` in `<role-name>AllAuthenticatedUser</role-name>`

Just try this and let me know whether it worked or not.