# Tomcat deployment fails with error 403

Tags: tomcat6

My tomcat deployment is failing every time with the following error:

403 Access Denied

You are not authorized to view this page.

This is my tomacat-users.xml:

```
    <?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
    <tomcat-users>
    <role rolename="manager-gui"/>
    <user username="bhaskar" password="bhaskar007" roles="manager-gui"/>
    </tomcat-users>
```

I don't know what am I doing wrong in this case. Tomcat manager is allowing me to login but not to deploy. Please help as I am prestty sure that my deployment path is correct.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to fix Tomcat HTTP Status 403: Access to the requested resource has been denied?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5808206/how-to-fix-tomcat-http-status-403-access-to-the-requested-resource-has-been-den)