# http status 403.description Access to the specified resource has been forbidden

Tags: java, tomcat, openam

I success fully installed openAM j2ee agent in my Apache Tomcat/6.0.43 in one VMWARE in my windows server2008 r2 .I installed the openAM in another vmware inside another apache tomcat server.There is a folder myapps inside my webapps folder.a html page new.html sending the action to another servlet called test.java.The web.xml is ok and tomcat-user.xml is also ok.But when i am entering data into html page and click ok its showing "http status 403.access to the specified resource is forbidden"

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to fix Tomcat HTTP Status 403: Access to the requested resource has been denied?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5808206/how-to-fix-tomcat-http-status-403-access-to-the-requested-resource-has-been-den)

Answer (score 0):

By default agents are enforcing URL policies as well, either change Agent mode or create URL policies as documented

Comment: thank you ,i entered the agent filter mode "sso_only" and its working fine