# Not able to Login successfully in JMeter

Tags: performance, jmeter, performance-testing, jmeter-plugins

We have recorded login functionality of a website using the **JMeter** RecordingController and then when we are trying to load test same functionality we have observed that GET login *https://example.com/login* is working fine but giving **response code 302** during POST login *https://example.com/login/Dologin* and then URL is redirected to **/errors/403**

I have attached screenshots for reference, please help me on this and let us know if more details required.
[image: Login Request]
[image: Login POST Sampler Request]
[image: Login POSR Response]

Comment: Try to send GET and not POST

Comment: There must be something you are sending that your server doesn't like.  Possibilities are: cookies you are sending are incomplete, expired or invalid; something in the request you are sending is not the same as when sent from the browser (this includes cookies, headers and body). Best is to ask developers what you are doing wrong. If not possible, compare successful request in the browser with yours, and make sure that cookie handling is done right (i.e. use Cookie Manager, and don't hard-code them).

Comment: @user7294900 - I have tried to do GET but it is redirecting to an error page https://example.com/errors/403

Comment: Here is the results of GET...


GET https://uat.example.com/errors/403

GET data:


Cookie Data:
JSESSIONID=D10EB175882F251EC610336A0A620BFB; AWSELB=196797810CFA0FD4250D5C45330E890B879B294516A4B9B962E5747B86E68693BE5F5A5B323E8475483749866977C6AE69FD3DD7273D4567B13F9AC4BC13287043F4076454A1DBE70917895FC492D0412C0A74F284

Request Headers:
Connection: keep-alive
Host: uat.example.com
User-Agent: Apache-HttpClient/4.5.3 (Java/1.8.0_111)

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5808206/how-to-fix-tomcat-http-status-403-access-to-the-requested-resource-has-been-den